# Mobile/wifi network exclamation mark

Tags: nexus-5, connection-issues, 5.1-lollipop

I have a problem that almost always my mobile network is marked with exclamation mark and I can't connect to Edge/3G, sometimes this happening to WiFi. I have a Nexus 5 and Android 5.1.1. I'm also trying to enable/disable airplane mode but it doesn't help.

About WiFi, I reload my WiFi router and after it it works fine. Mobile network - it's happening at two cities and seems for everybody around me everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation mark means you have no data connection. Go to *Settings* and in category *Wireless & networks*  enable **Mobile Networks**. This assumes *Airplane mode* is off.

Comment: It's enabled all the time